# Detect collision with line, tetris like game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm doing a game like tetris. There are objects which are falling from the top to the bottom of the screen. When the pile of object reach the line, the game is over.
I tried to set a boolean to detect when the object pass 2 time in the line the game ends, but it don't work like that so I don't really know how to do this.
Maybe we can detect if the object stands on the line more than 2 seconds ?
Thanks

[image]

**EDIT:**

To simplify the problem I put the line of the top of the screen (self.frame.height), and I spawn the objects under this line, so they never cross the line before the game is over.

The problem now is I have to spawn the objects 40 pixels below the line, or a collision is detected at the spawn point. (It does nothing if I set usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true).

So the 40 pixels collision detection are normal ?

[image]

Comment: You could test if a piece is touching the line and its physicsBody's resting property is YES.

Comment: I tried but I can't use physicsbody.resting because some item are rounded and keep moving a very little

Comment: Create a BOOL property for your tile objects. Set this BOOL to yes when it touches another object. If a BOOL yes object touches the line, game over.

Comment: well, it was a nice idea but in my game there is several items which are drop from the top, and the items can collide each other from the beginning

Comment: How about if a node's physicsBody.velocity is less than a small number and it touches the line?

Comment: I change the line position to easier to solve the problem. Check my edit please. Thank again guys

Comment: No, a 40-pt difference shouldn't trigger a contact event. Make sure your contactTestBitMask is set correctly, the physicsBody of the line matches its texture, and your are detecting the contact of the line and a piece not a piece contacting another piece.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the item pass the line 2 times? Items always move down. So really, once an item is past the line, you *know* it will never go above (Well, OK, that's not true -- since you can rotate an item, you could get a long one horizontal and then rotate it to vertical ... do Tetris items come out horizontally?).

So really, your test would be more "does it never fully cross the line". E.g. if you know that an item moves at speed X, you could probably just calculate the time it should take to move from top to past the line, then wait that long, then see if it still intersects the top area above the line. If it does, the game is lost.

Alternately, you could set a flag when an item comes to rest on another item. If that flag is set, *and* the item still intersects the area above the line, the game is lost.

PS - Keep in mind that Tetris is a brand name. Be sure to name your game something else. :-)